# Finding last added row of 1:m or adding reference

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm keeping historic data of changes and using a separate row (`item_status_id`) to store the last added status:

```
CREATE TABLE `item`(
  `item_id`        INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_status_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES item_status(item_status_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `item_status`(
  `item_status_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ts_created`     TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `info`           TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_status_id`)
);
```

The problem is that the update requires the application (or a stored procedure) to update the `item_status_id` row of the `item` table, but it makes my 1:1 join dead simple, compared to a join using the TOP record sorted using the timestamp.

Is it better practice to use JOIN TOP on a subquery, or a table design that relies more on the application?

Comment: Are you really using TSQL or MySQL?  Please update your tags.

Comment: The design that you've presented is duplicating data in the database, which is generally a bad idea. You end up with maintenance issues for the data (making sure that it stays in sync) and issues where the data gets out of sync. Unless you run into an **actual** performance issue, it's a bad idea, IMO.

Comment: what if instead of duplicating the data, I put the `item_status` fields such as `info` as part of the `item` table, and convert the `item_status` to a `item_status_history`, where the old column values would be moved to before they are updated. That way the other table would only serve as a way to look up the changes in past. That would not have any duplicate data being stored.